# github requires a personal access token, but still does not accept them

Tags: github

I wanted to push my react project to github, but if I try putting in my username and password, I get this message:
[image]
The annoying part is when I try using a personal access token instead, I get the `"fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/samisamara/personalWebpage.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403"` error.

I used all saved tokens I had on me (I always remember to save my tokens so I don't lose them) and I even tried to make a new token, but neither worked. So git is making me use my github password instead of a personal access token, but it also requires a personal access token instead. I'm basically locked out of doing any commits, and I have no idea what to do. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to this. When you generate a new token, you have to check mark the "repo" checkbox. I didn't check mark that last time, so the key didn't have permission to actually do anything.

Comment: Note that this is purely a GitHub issue: GitHub tokens can encode permissions. Git doesn't know a GitHub token from a subway token or any other kind of token; you just have Git send the string *to* GitHub.